# Compiling Vaadin 8 Widget Set

Tags: vaadin8

I am new to Vaadin. I am trying to use the GoogleMaps add-on in my project which compiled fine. The challenge however is that I get an exception at runtime which I do not understand. Googling, I found out that I had to compile the `WidgetSet`. How can this be achieved? Any help in showing me steps will be appreciated. Contents of widgetset.xml and where it should be placed too

Below are my code and the runtime exception I get:

```
import com.labafrique.creporter.model.ReportModel;
import com.labafrique.creporter.repository.ReportRepository;
import com.vaadin.navigator.View;
import com.vaadin.tapio.googlemaps.GoogleMap;
import com.vaadin.ui.Composite;
import com.vaadin.ui.VerticalLayout;
import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

/**
 *
 * @author Javalove
 */

public class View1 extends Composite implements View {
    
    
    GoogleMap map;
    
    @Autowired
    ReportRepository report;
    
    public View1()
    {
        map = new GoogleMap("", null, "english");
        VerticalLayout v = new VerticalLayout();
        map.setSizeFull();
        v.addComponent(map);
        setCompositionRoot(v);
    }
    
    public void initMap()
    {
        List<ReportModel> lx = report.findAllCases();
    }

    
    
}
```

And the exception

```
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to create an instance of {0}. 
 The constructor threw an exception.
                            at
```

Comment: Is your project based on standard Vaadin maven archetype?

Comment: Yes it is... and I am using NetBeans IDE.

Comment: Ok, then you should just do "mvn clean install" or equivalent call from IDE.

Comment: I have done that...I used Clean and Build and still notning happens. Even my Autowired classes are returning null in views... I have been on this for 48 hours

Comment: When you did run "mvn clean install" was it fast or slow? If it is slow its good, since it should take a while. Did you get any errors during the compile?

Comment: It has compiled successfully... Thanks yout @TatuLund ... I had to build...cleared browser cache.... Now I have a different problem.... It says "Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.vaadin.tapio.googlemaps.client.GoogleMapState cannot be cast to com.vaadin.shared.ui.AbstractComponentContainerState" ... I dont know how to fix that.... thanks for your help so far